# How to get year in formate dd/mm/yyyy in javascript

Tags: javascript, date

for example

```
var date = '18-02-2015';
```

How i can get the year? just the year.
if i use getFullYear() -> it just process formate MM-DD-YYYY

Sorry for my bad English

Comment: Where does the `date` come from? The user, is it dynamically created to "today's" date (whenever it runs) or is it hard-coded?

Comment: The date comes from user who choose manual date .
But i just need the year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach, taking advantage of HTML's `<input type="date" />` element, is:

```js
function findYearFrom() {
  // if it's not of 'type="date"', or it has no value,
  // or the value is equal to the default-value:
  if (this.type !== 'date' || !this.value || this.value === this.defaultValue) {
    // we return here
    return false;
  }

  // we get the value of the element as a date, and then
  // call getFullYear() on that value:
  console.log(this.valueAsDate.getFullYear());
  return this.valueAsDate.getFullYear();
}

// binding the named-function as the change event-handler
// for this element:
document.getElementById('demo').addEventListener('change', findYearFrom);
```

```html
<input id="demo" type="date" value="2015-02-18" />
```

Answer (score 2):

if you are sure that the format is dd-MM-YYYY then split the string and switch it then parse it as a date.

```
    var date = '18-02-2015';
    var input = date.split("-");
    var dateObject = new Date(input[2] +"-"+ input[1] +"-"+ input[0]);
    console.log(dateObject);

    var year = dateObject.getFullYear();
    //or without parsing simply
    var year = input[2];
```

Answer (score 1):

if you know that the format always is dd-mm-yyyy you can do

```
var date = "18-02-2015"    
var year = date.substring(date.lastIndexOf("-")+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.

```
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
if(dd<10){
    dd='0'+dd
} 
if(mm<10){
    mm='0'+mm
} 
var today = dd+'/'+mm+'/'+yyyy;
```

Refer  [JS Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ubR5m/224/)

Comment: if i use formate "DD/MM/YYYY"
function getFullYear it doesnt running, any others way?

Comment: you can use substring to get what you want like  today.getFullYear().toString().substr(2,2); you can refer the js fiddle

Comment: can you give me a example code? please
var tgl_pemberian = document.getElementById("TGL_PERUNTUKKAN").value;
var years = tgl_pemberian.getFullYear().toString().substr(2,4);
alert ('years'); <--  that is right?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at http://momentjs.com/

This should work for you to get just the year.

```
var day = moment("18-02-2015", "MM-DD-YYYY");
console.log(day.format("YYYY"));
```

Answer (score 0):

With RegExp:

```js
var year = function(str) {
  return str.match(/\d{4}$/)[0]; // \d{4}, four digits group from the end
};

alert(year('18/02/2015'));
alert(year('02/18/2004'));
```

With slice():

```js
var year = function(str) {
  return str.slice(-4);// get last four characters
};

alert(year('01/12/2015'));
alert(year('18/02/2004'));
```

Comment: Thx brother it works in here but in my web isnt did.
I am sorry for wrong information 
My formate date is : '18/02/2015'
can you give me a solution please

Answer (score 0):

If the date you're working with is simply a string,  then all you're trying to do is get the last 4 characters of the string, which make up the year.

Assuming that the date is always in the format you listed, use slice():

```
var date = '18-02-2015';
var year = date.slice(-4);
```

If the date needs to be an integer type, then use this instead:

```
var year = parseInt(date.slice(-4));
```